# Azure automation with cosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-automation

Trying to perform some updates to CosmosDB  with the Azure automation run books. I have made a RunAs service principal Account to authenticate with Azure

Updating the Modules used for the Get-AzureRmResource  appear to cause some issues where I can no longer retrieve the CosmosDB   object.

```
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"
Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID `
-ApplicationID $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint 
$Conn.CertificateThumbprint

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "Visual Studio Enterprise" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

   #resource and app variables declared here.

$cosmosDbResource = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType 
"Microsoft.DocumentDb/DatabaseAccounts" -ResourceGroup $applicationGroup - 
ApiVersion "2015-04-08" -Name $cosmosDBName)

"Before CosmosDB Resource"
$cosmosDbResource | FT
"Cosmos DB Properties"
$cosmosDbResource.Properties
```

This code works just fine on the plain deployment of automation accounts with the module. AzureRM.Resources  at 1.0.3.

If I try and update the AzureRM.Resource and its dependencies to 6.1.0   I can no longer retrieve my CosmosDB instance.

I think that there may be a conflict with the powershell modules with the update

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you wish to update within cosmosdb.....

The official cosmosdb powershell modules are pretty laking at the moment, take a look at the community cosmosdb powershell module it is *far* more feature rich and easier to work with:

https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB

Comment: very nice to know about additional powershell modules to work with cosmosDB,  but I have already worked with the rest api to affect my cosmos instances directly, so I have not tested to see if this fixes my issues in the runbooks.